# What is the equivalent of <Ctrl>+<Shift>+<End> in Vim?

Tags: vim, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any equivalent for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> in VIM which can select all text from current cursor position to the end of the file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>.

- [<kbd>v</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#v): start Visual mode per character
- [<kbd>G</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#G): Goto line [count], default last line, on the first non-blank character.
- [<kbd>$</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#$): To the end of the line.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks a lot! Is there similar key combination in `vi` which doesn't have visual mode?

Comment: @Stacker: this question doesn't make sense in the context of `vi`. What are you actually trying to do and in which editor?

Comment: @Johnsyweb actually I use both `vi` and `vim`. Your solution is perfectly fine for vim, was just curious to know how vi does text selection.

Comment: Vi doesn't have a visual mode.

Comment: in vi, if you want a motion operator to go till last character of the file characterwise you can try `1000000000000go`. Except for files of more than 1TB`

Answer (score 2):

Often times you are better off executing your specific desire instead of just selecting.  For instance to "yank" use:

<kbd>yG</kbd>

To "yank" into clipboard:

<kbd>"*yG</kbd>

Another option might be "delete":

<kbd>dG</kbd>

Comment: I do not believe `yG` yanks from the **current cursor position** like the OP requested

Comment: It indeed yanks from the current **line**.